# Tips for faster pandas slicing and column sum calculation

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I want to improve the comp. performance in different sections of my code and was just wondering how I would go about it in the pandas sections.

E.g., to tackle the sum calculation for certain columns, I compared a few examples based on a small DataFrame

### 1)

```
%timeit -n 5 -r 1000 df[['week_points', 'month_points', 'dk_avg_points', 'home']].sum(axis=0)
```

5 loops, best of 1000: 911 µs per loop

### 2)

```
%timeit -n 5 -r 1000 df[['week_points', 'month_points', 'dk_avg_points', 'home']].values.sum(axis=0)
```

5 loops, best of 1000: 716 µs per loop

### 3)

```
%timeit -n 5 -r 1000 df['week_points'].sum(); df['month_points'].sum(); avg_pts = df['dk_avg_points'].sum(); df['home'].sum()
```

5 loops, best of 1000: 411 µs per loop

### 4)

```
%timeit -n 5 -r 1000 df['week_points'].values.sum(); df['month_points'].values.sum(); avg_pts = df['dk_avg_points'].values.sum(); df['home'].values.sum()
```

5 loops, best of 1000: 17.2 µs per loop

Number 3 & 4 really surprised me. Why would it be so much faster to calculate the sum for every column separately? Do I have an error of thought here, or is there some explanation for this?

And it would also be nice if you have any further ideas to improve the speed for the calculation!
Thanks!

Comment: I would guess it's because getting multiple columns requires creation of a new DataFrame, which has overhead costs, whereas getting one column can return the existing Series directly.  It may also depend on the nature of your data; when I try a similar thing the speed gain for single-column access is much smaller.

Comment: Along these lines instead of individual columns you could also use `[df[col].values.sum(axis=0) for col in ('week_points', 'month_points', 'dk_avg_points', 'home')]`